# how to pass a message from go and consuming it from nestjs with rabbitmq?

Tags: node.js, go, rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

I have a `go` service that publishes a message to `rabbitmq` and the code which is responsible for that part is as below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func main() {
    conn, amqError := amqp.Dial("amqp://localhost:5672/")
    if amqError != nil {
        panic(amqError)
    }

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "default", // name
        true,      // durable
        false,     // delete when unused
        false,     // exclusive
        false,     // no-wait
        nil,       // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    body := "{ \"body\":\"Hello...\", \"pattern\":\"test\",  \"age\":\"20\"}"

    err = ch.Publish(
        "",     // exchange
        q.Name, // routing key
        false,  // mandatory
        false,  // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            ContentType: "text/plain",
            Body:        []byte(body),
        },
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

}

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}
```

And the `Nestjs` part that is consuming the message is as:

```js
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Ctx, EventPattern, Payload, RmqContext } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor() { }

  @EventPattern("test")
  getEventMessage(@Payload() data: any, @Ctx() context: RmqContext) {
    console.log("data is -> ", data) // always undefined
    console.log(
      "content of message is -> ",
      JSON.parse(
        context.getMessage().content.toString() // from buffer to string
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that I can't get the message from data instead of parsing it from `ctx`, also I need to send the message in go as `json` without skipping double quotes like this `"\""`

Comment: That looks expected, [per the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/rabbitmq#context)

Comment: @edd  so what was the reason for adding the `@Payload` decorator to the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the response to your questions:

1. In the examples of NextJS they don't provide how to use the payload data, instead of it, they [say](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/rabbitmq#context):

> To access the original RabbitMQ message (with the properties, fields,
> and content), use the getMessage() method of the RmqContext

Given the above statement, you are parsing properly the message in the queue.

2. Avoiding to do manually the body string to send, you should use a process called json Marhsal of struct, for example:

- You should create a struct that contains the information to send to queue
- Marshal struct and generates the `[]byte`

```golang
type MessageQueue struct {
    Body    string `json:"body"`
    Pattern string `json:"pattern"`
    Age     string `json:"age"`
    Data    string `json:"data"`
}

func NewMessageQueue(body, pattern, age string, data) *MessageQueue {
    return &MessageQueue{
        body, pattern, age, data
    }
}

func (m *MessageQueue) Marshal() ([]byte, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(m)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return bytes, err
}

func main() {
    ...

    message := NewMessageQueue("Hello...", "test", "20", "data...")
    // TODO: check the error
    body, _ := message.Marshal()

    err = ch.Publish(
        "",         // exchange
        q.Name,     // routing key
        false,      // mandatory
        false,      // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            ContentType: "text/plain",
            Body:        body,
        },
    )

    ...
}
```

**Update:**

3. The `data` param received by controller on `getEventMessage` method, it should be sent on body from Golang to be deserialized by `Nestjs`. It means the structure should be the following:

```golang
type MessageQueue struct {
    Body    string `json:"body"`
    Pattern string `json:"pattern"`
    Age     string `json:"age"`
    Data    string `json:"data"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the  JSON manipulation of the go part, but what was the reason for adding the `@Payload` decorator to the first place in `nestjs`  handler?

Comment: thanks for your solution. so I think they are just manipulating `data` field from `queue` as I am testing for `(@Payload age: string)` it doesn't log age just `data` so I should make my json like `{ "pattern": "test", "data": { age: 20 }}` for better convention